# How to modify Spring Template Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i created the basic Spring +Jdbc seeing the following [Spring + JDBC example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-jdbc-example/)

For this i used the Spring Template Project

i added all the classes inside `src/main/java/`

But now as i run the project by rightclicking the App.java Class ->run as->run on server.

it gives me the following error.

```
Requested Resource is not found.
```

url above is `/app/WEB-INF/classes/com/shr/common/App.java`

Now do i need to add the classes to WEB-INF/classes folder?
how should i run my project. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a web application. You have to start it as Java Application (run as -> Java Application)